# Base class functions that use derived class variables

Tags: c++, class, derived

In c++, Is there a standard way to create a function in a base class that can use the variables of derived classes?

```
class Foo{
private:
    int x;
public: 
    Foo(){
        x = 2;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Foo{
private:
    int x;
public: 
    Derived(){
        x = 4;
    }

};


void main()
{
    Derived a;
    a.print();
}
```

This code prints the variable of the base class ( 2 ). Is there a way to make a function used by many derived classes to use the class's private variables without passing them as parameters?

Edit: My intentions are, to avoid writing the same code for each derived class. 
For example, I want a get_var() in all, but this function should return the variable of that own class. I know I can make virtual and override, but I was looking for a way that I don't need to write again and again.

Comment: A base class should not know anything about its derived types. To require that is a bad design.

Comment: You'll need to implement a virtual `getA` method.

Comment: If you declare 'x' as protected in Foo and not declare it again in Derived. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I want my derived classes to have a function that does the same, but with their own variables. Each has different values.

Comment: @user3023605 make `print()` virtual and override it in derived classes

Comment: use protected on the member(s) that should be avaliable for your derived classes. `protected: int x;`. The keyword `virtual` makes methods overridable.

Comment: But then I have to write the function again for each derived class, that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @user3023605 IMO if **many derived classes share same data and code** then...you may introduce a new common base class for them (which is not base class now you have).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible for the base class to access anything in the derived class directly. The only way for a derived class to share anything with its base class is by overriding virtual member functions of the base class.

In your case, however, this is not necessary: the derived class can set variable `x` in the base class once you make it `protected`, and drop its own declaration as unnecessary:

```
class Foo{
protected: // Make x visible to derived classes
    int x;
public: 
    Foo(){
        x = 2;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Foo{
public: 
    Derived(){
        x = 4;
    }
};
```

Comment: will this override the base class x? If I make multiple derived, will they all share the same x/value?

Comment: @user3023605 every instance of a derived class also has an instance of the base class. So no, each instance has its own `x`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I hope there's no drawbacks with his method.

Comment: @user3023605 There is only one `x` per instance of `Foo` or a class derived from Foo. The value is shared across subclasses, but only within the bounds of a single object; other instances of `Foo` or classes derived from it will get their own `x`.